# Question on how to finish this metric space q?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have this question which is stated below:

> Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$ where d is the distance defined by:
> $$d(x,y) = |x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}| \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
> Q: Let $A= (0,1).$  Show that A is an open set in $(\mathbb{R},d)$.

I have the following definition which says $(X,d)$ metric space then U subset of X is said to be open set if given any $x \in U \  \exists \ r > 0 \ s.t. \ B_r(x) \subseteq U$

I am thinking along the lines of let us take a random $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then there exists $r > 0 s.t. B_r^{d} (a)$ exists defined to be $|a^{1/3} - r^{1/3}|$ and perhaps we could define $r = min \left \{ |a-1|, |a-0| \right \}$ ?

Is this a valid approach or is there something i'm doing wrong / missing?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $d'$ be the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$ and consider the cube function $c : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $c(x) = x^3$. Then $c(x)$ is bijective as its inverse $r: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $r(x) = \sqrt[3]x$.

Then for any $x, y \in \Bbb{R}$, we have:

$$
d'(x, y) = |x - y| = d(c(x), c(y))
$$
and
$$
d(x, y) = |r(x) - r(y)| = d'(x, y)
$$

What this is telling you is that $d$ and $d'$ are the same metric but with the real numbers taking on different disguises. In the usual jargon, $c$ and $r$ establish a homeomorphism (in fact an isometry) between the two metric spaces $(d', \Bbb{R})$ and $(d, \Bbb{R})$, which implies that $c$ maps open subsets of $(d', \Bbb{R})$ to open subsets of $(d, \Bbb{R})$ and vice versa. As $c[(0, 1)] = (0, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$ is open in $(d', \Bbb{R})$, $(0, 1)$ is also open in $(d, \Bbb{R})$.

If that all sounds a bit abstract, just use $c$ and $r$ to convert a proof that $(0, 1)$ is open in the usual metric to a proof that it is open in this new metric $d$. You have made a good start on the proof that it is open in the usual metric.